# How to read a line of a file, assign it to a variable, search it in another file, and when done move on to the next line of the file?

Tags: python

This is for a project I am working on and I have simplified my issue. I have two files at hand. First file contains a list of terms such as:

```
dog
apple
gold
boy
tomato
```

My second file contains a paragraph possibly containing the terms found in 1st file, but does not have to. Example:

```
the dog for some reason had a grand 
appetite for eating golden apples, 
but the dog did not like eating tomatoes
the dog only likes eating gold colored foods
```

My goal is to open the 1st file, assign variable "wanted_word" the term on the first line (in this case "dog"). Then I want to search for this "wanted_word" in the second file in each line. If the string is found, I want to create a file that contains the first 3 terms of the line that the "wanted_word" is found in. So the output I want would be:

```
the dog for
but the dog
the dog only
```

With my current code, I can achieve this. My issue is that after the file is created, I want to move onto the string on the next line in the first file (in this case: "apple"). The idea of the code is to repeat the whole process, create a new file each time a string in first file is found in the second file. If the string is not in the 2nd file, then I want the program to move onto next line.

My code so far:

```
def word_match(Listofwords, string):
    wordnumber = 0
    listOfAssociatedWords = []
    with open(Listofwords, 'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            wordnumber += 1
            if string in line:
                listOfAssociatedWords.append(line.split()[:3])
    return listOfAssociatedWords
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Firstfile = open("/Directory/firstfilename", "r")
wanted_word = Firstfile.readline(3) #This part also undermines my goal since I limit the read to 3 chars
Firstfile.close()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
matched_words = word_match("/Directory/secondfilename", wanted_word)
NewFile = open(wanted_word + '.txt', "w") #this is for the file creation part
for elem in matched_words:
    NewFile.write(elem[0] + "  " + elem[1] + "  " + elem[2])
    NewFile.write("\n")
```

So at the end, by this logic I would have 4 files, with the exception of "boy" which was not in the second file. I am aware I need a loop, but my inexperience with Python requires a need for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over words, and inside of the loop go over each line:

```
with open("/Directory/firstfilename") as words:
    for word in words:
        found_lines = []
        with open("/Directory/secondfilename") as lines:
            for line in lines:
                if word in line:
                    found_lines.append(' '.join(line.split()[:3]))
        if found_lines:
            with open(word + '.txt', 'w') as out_file:
                for line in found_lines:
                    out_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: @gold_cy The output files need to be opened inside the loop. The "secondfilename" can be opened outside but would require `seek(0)` at the end of each iteration. I can't argue which is faster seeking or reopening, because I don't know. If you do, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I guess I misread the question, I didn't see that OP wants a new file for every word, that doesn't seem like a good approach to me, I'll remove my original comment

Comment: For some reason this code just looks up the last line in my first file. Any reason why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

This should write a new file "wordsX" for every mathing word in your paragraph list

```
def wordMatch(wordListFileLocation, paragraphListFileLocation):
    fileCounter = 0 

    with open(paragraphListFileLocation) as file:
        paragraphs = file.readlines()

    with open(wordListFileLocation) as wordListFile:
        for word in wordListFile:
            matching = [s for s in paragraphs if word in s]
            if len(matching):
                with open('words{0}.txt'.format(fileCounter), 'w') as newFile:
                    words = matching[0]
                    firstWords = words[0:3]
                    line = firstWords.join(' ')
                    newFile.write(line)
                    fileCounter += 1
```